# Get text from a tag name using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is the Python Selenium code I am trying to use to get the title of the articles:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")

search = driver.find_element_by_name("s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
             EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
           )
    articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
    for article in articles:
        header = article.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[0]
        #print(header.get_attribute('href'))
        print(header.text)

finally:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

The code is working well when extracting the `href` attribute, but it didn't work for the *.text* as I got empty lines instead of the headers of the articles

How can I fix that?

Comment: header for the link?

Comment: I have updated the post and added a snapshot of the first desired title `HTTP Methods - GET & POST`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may mean

```
print(header.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

To replace the ampersand sign, try

```
print(header.get_attribute('innerHTML').replace('&amp;', '&'))
```

Or just use the [*innerText* property](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp):

```
print(header.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

Or the *textContent* Property:

```
print(header.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot. How can I get the ampersand instead of `GET &amp; POST`

Comment: I tried `print(header.get_attribute('innerText'))` and this works well. Thanks a lot for great help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is the problem of using `innerText` as there may be other special characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awesome help. Best Regards